# subtracting unique pair-wise objects from for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, combinations

I'm trying to *subtract* each *unique pair-wise* `p`s from the `for` loop in my function below. To do so, I **first** find *unique pair-wise* `p`s using `combn(p, 2)` and **second** use `outer` to subtract each unique pair from each other.

In both steps, I get error. Is there a fix for the error?

```
prop <- function(n, yes, a, b = a){

    p <- list()

    for(i in 1:length(n)){
        p[[i]] <- rbeta(2, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
    }
    outer(combn(p, 2), FUN = "-")    # Gives Error
}

prop(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it is `simplify = TRUE` in `combn`.  So, even though the output is a `list`, it is simplified to have a `dim` attribute by converting each of the the `list` as elements in a `matrix`.  As the `m` is 2, there are 2 `list` elements for each comparison, extract those elements using `[[` and subtract

```
combn(p, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]]- x[[2]])
```

-full function

```
prop <- function(n, yes, a, b = a){

   p <- list()

   for(i in 1:length(n)){
     p[[i]] <- rbeta(2, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
    }
    combn(p, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]]- x[[2]])
   }

prop(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3))
```

---

If we wanted to include another argument `how`

```
prop <- function(n, yes, a, b = a, how= "one.two"){
  delta <- switch(how, 
             one.two = function(x) x[[1]] - x[[2]],
             two.one = function(x) x[[2]] - x[[1]])
  p <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(n)){
     p[[i]] <- rbeta(2, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
   }

    out <-  combn(p, 2, FUN = delta)
    nm1 <- paste0("p", combn(seq_along(p), 2, FUN = paste, collapse="-"))
    colnames(out) <- nm1
    out

 }

prop(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3), how = "one.two")

prop(n = c(10, 20, 30), yes = rep(5, 3), a = rep(1, 3), how = "two.one")
```